# ul li breaking when its upper li have long text

Tags: html, css

when my li's height is increasing due to 2 line text of title, the li that should be dsiplayed right below of the list item is pushed to right, in my image there are 2 consecutive list items of 2 text, thats why my list item on next line is pushed right after 2 list items. the 6th image that have is pushed to right has class "tibox-6" other have class "tibox"

My CSS

```
.tibox{
    float:left;
}
.tibox-6{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}
```

My HTML

```
<ul class="movies">
    <li class="tibox">
        <a class="timovie_image" href="new-image-wrestling/"
            title="Permalink to New Image wrestling">
        <img width="166" height="250" src="15-166x250.jpg" class="attachment-166x250 wp-post-image" alt="1" />  
        </a>
        <div class="timovie_desc">
            <div><a class="timovie_link" href="new-image-wrestling/">New Image wrestling</a></div>
            <div class="timovie_year">2014</div>
            <div class="timovie_rating"><img src="image1.png" /> 6.4 - <img src="image2.png" /> 50%</div>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li class="tibox">
        <a class="timovie_image" href="new-image-pakistani/"
            title="Permalink to New Image pakistani">
        <img width="166" height="250" src="15-166x250.jpg" class="attachment-166x250 wp-post-image" alt="1" />  
        </a>
        <div class="timovie_desc">
            <div><a class="timovie_link" href="new-image-pakistani/">New Image pakistani</a></div>
            <div class="timovie_year">2014</div>
            <div class="timovie_rating"><img src="image1.png" /> 6.4 - <img src="image2.png" /> 50%</div>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li class="tibox">
        <a class="timovie_image" href="new-image-1-8/"
            title="Permalink to New Image 1 sad sad asd as dsad">
        <img width="166" height="250" src="15-166x250.jpg" class="attachment-166x250 wp-post-image" alt="1" />  
        </a>
        <div class="timovie_desc">
            <div><a class="timovie_link" href="new-image-1-8/">New Image 1 sad sad asd as dsad</a></div>
            <div class="timovie_year">2014</div>
            <div class="timovie_rating"><img src="image1.png" /> 6.4 - <img src="image2.png" /> 50%</div>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li class="tibox">
        <a class="timovie_image" href="new-image-1-9/"
            title="Permalink to New Image 1">
        <img width="166" height="250" src="15-166x250.jpg" class="attachment-166x250 wp-post-image" alt="1" />  
        </a>
        <div class="timovie_desc">
            <div><a class="timovie_link" href="new-image-1-9/">New Image 1</a></div>
            <div class="timovie_year">2014</div>
            <div class="timovie_rating"><img src="image1.png" /> 6.4 - <img src="image2.png" /> 50%</div>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li class="tibox">
        <a class="timovie_image" href="new-image-1-10/"
            title="Permalink to New Image 1">
        <img width="166" height="250" src="15-166x250.jpg" class="attachment-166x250 wp-post-image" alt="1" />  
        </a>
        <div class="timovie_desc">
            <div><a class="timovie_link" href="new-image-1-10/">New Image 1</a></div>
            <div class="timovie_year">2014</div>
            <div class="timovie_rating"><img src="image1.png" /> 6.4 - <img src="image2.png" /> 50%</div>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li class="tibox">
        <a class="timovie_image" href="new-image-1-11/"
            title="Permalink to New Image 2">
        <img width="166" height="250" src="15-166x250.jpg" class="attachment-166x250 wp-post-image" alt="1" />  
        </a>
        <div class="timovie_desc">
            <div><a class="timovie_link" href="new-image-1-11/">New Image 2</a></div>
            <div class="timovie_year">2014</div>
            <div class="timovie_rating"><img src="image1.png" /> 6.4 - <img src="image2.png" /> 50%</div>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li class="tibox-6">
        <a class="timovie_image" href="new-image-1-12/"
            title="Permalink to New Image 1">
        <img width="166" height="250" src="15-166x250.jpg" class="attachment-166x250 wp-post-image" alt="1" />  
        </a>
        <div class="timovie_desc">
            <div><a class="timovie_link" href="new-image-1-12/">New Image 1</a></div>
            <div class="timovie_year">2014</div>
            <div class="timovie_rating"><img src="image1.png" /> 6.4 - <img src="image2.png" /> 50%</div>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Image Link Webpage https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctjq6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `display: inline-block` instead of floats:

```
.tibox {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I'm not sure how to move to the next row with every sixth element though. You could try replacing each `tibox-6` with just `tibox` and setting width of parent `ul` element.

Comment: thank you :) it solved my problem will save your solution in text file also for future use :) thank you once again